# Not inserting on DB bot/spider/crawlers activity

Tags: php, mysql, bots

On my webpage I register the visitors' activity for analysis.

However the results are affected by the bots visits.

I'd like to know if checking the user_agent before saving data on the DB is a smart approach (see function at the bottom). I'm worry about the heavy-load on my web. There are a lot of bots and I don't know if is efficient, in each visit, to check the user_agent vs. a 30 bots list.

```
$bots = array( 'googlebot', 'msnbot', 'baidu', ... up to 30 );
$isRobot = false;
$ua = strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );

foreach ( $bots as $bot ) {
        if ( strpos( $ua, $bot ) !== false )
            $isRobot = true;
        }

        if ( !$isRobot ) {
            // insert in the db
        }
    }
```

Alternative would be to allow the insertion on the DB and delete them afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Use [in_array](http://php.net/in_array):

```
$bots = array( 'googlebot', 'msnbot', 'baidu', ... up to 30 );
$isRobot = false;
$ua = strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );

if(in_array($ua, $bots)) {
    $isRobot = true;
}
if ( !$isRobot ) {
    // insert in the db
}
```